# Generate the edit Path of Infopath for Document library item

Tags: infopath, forms-services, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections, document-info-panel

- We are creating the item in document library from SharePoint List designer workflow and on it's item creation in document library we are loosing edit path of infopath for item in library, which is designed with infopath form.
- Can any one help me in knowing ,while creating the item from list designer workflow, How can I generate the url of the infopath form to edit the item of document library

[image]

Comment: Share the workflow steps of how you creating item, better a screen grab. Are you try to calc the item edit url

Comment: The above snap shows that I am creating the item in document library (VMDLB).And that is having the (Path and Name) column which holds the url of the infopath form of an.And I am loosing the url